# Can I use inet_pton to set a textual address for my TCP socket server like "device1.local"?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, dns

I've written a TCP socket in C and it needs to work with a mobile app that connects to this address over a local network: "`device1.local:6666`".

Every example I find for using `inet_pton()` to set the server address has either an IPV4 address that looks like this: `192.168.1.34`, or an IPV6 address that looks like this: `2001:db8:8714:3a90::12`. Which format do I specify if I want my client to telnet to "`device1.local`" instead of a numeric or hex address? How do I set up my TCP socket server to answer that address?

This doesn't work:

```
local_socket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(local_socket < 0) {
    printf("unable to create socket\n");
    return false;
}
printf("socket created\n");

bzero((void *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
int s_code = inet_pton(AF_INET6, "device1.local", &server_address.sin6_addr);
server_address.sin6_port = htons(port_number);

printf("inet_pton returned: %d\n", s_code);

char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &server_address.sin6_addr, str, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("address from inet_ntop(): %s\n", str);
```

Here's the output:

```
socket created
inet_pton returned: 0
address from inet_ntop(): ::
```

I realize I'm probably demonstrating a fundamental lack of understanding about how the internet (or local networks) work. Any relevant links that you can give me so I can learn more about how custom textual addresses work would be appreciated.

Comment: You can have your client accept URLs (like web browsers do or telnet clients) but ultimately, those need to be resolved to network addresses when using the socket API functions that require them. You have no choice; underlying protocols use adresses (not even the dotted addresses are real network addresses, like URLs, they are only for the convenience of humans, not computers).

Comment: What do you mean by my client accepting a URL? I want the server to connect to a client who requests the address `device1.local`.

Comment: Then your server becomes a client and the same principle applies. By client, I mean any process that establishes a connection to a server. Servers can also be clients. Regardless, to connect over a network by using the sockets API, you will have to resolve names to network addresses. Perhaps I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the gethostbyname() function. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated. Use `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.local` TLD is reserved for mDNS, as described in [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762).

Therefore for `device.local` to work your local system should be set with `device` as its hostname and should be running a Bonjour service (built-in to Windows and OSX, available as Avahi on Linux).

Once that's done, your server-side application doesn't need to do anything special at all - it should just `bind` to `INADDR_ANY` and accept incoming (IPv4) connections on any interface.

To slightly complicate matters, if you want to serve over IPv6 too then you typically need two listening sockets, with the second one bound to `in6addr_any`.

On the client side, the `getaddrinfo()` function should be able to hook into mDNS and resolve the name to the correct IP address accordingly.

Comment: "*To slightly complicate matters, if you want to serve over IPv6 too then you typically need two listening sockets, with the second one bound to `in6addr_any`*" - unless you use a dual-stack socket, which can serve both IPv4 and IPv6 clients.

Answer (score 3):

> Which format do I specify if I want my client to telnet to "device1.local" instead of a numeric or hex address?

`inet_pton()` converts a textual representation of an IP address into its binary format (`in_addr` for IPv4, `in6_addr` for IPv6, etc).  You cannot use it to resolve a hostname into an IP address.  For that, you need to use either `gethostbyname()` (deprecated) or `getaddrinfo()` (preferred).

Here is a `gethostbyname()` example:

```
int connect_to_addr(const sockaddr *addr, int addrlen)
{
    local_socket = socket(addr->sa_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (local_socket == -1)
    {
        printf("unable to create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    unsigned short port;

    switch (addr->sa_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(saddr->sin6_addr), str, sizeof(str));
            port = ntohs(saddr->sin_port);
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(saddr->sin6_addr), str, sizeof(str));
            port = ntohs(saddr->sin6_port);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("connecting to address: %s on port: %hu\n", str, port);

    if (connect(local_socket, addr, addrlen) != 0)
    {
        printf("unable to connect\n");

        close(local_socket);
        local_socket = -1;

        return 0;
    }

    printf("connected\n");
    return 1;
}
```

```
bool connect_to_host(const char *hostname, unsigned short port_number)
{
    local_socket = -1;

    sockaddr_storage server_address;
    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, hostname, &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)&server_address)->sin6_addr)) == 1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in6 *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&server_address;

        saddr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
        saddr->sin6_port = htons(port_number);

        if (connect_to_addr((struct sockaddr*)saddr, sizeof(*saddr)) != 1)
            return false;
    }
    else if (inet_pton(AF_INET, hostname, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)&server_address)->sin_addr)) == 1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&server_address;

        saddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
        saddr->sin_port = htons(port_number);

        if (connect_to_addr((struct sockaddr*)saddr, sizeof(*saddr)) != 1)
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("resolving %s\n", hostname);

        struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(hostname);
        if (!host)
        {
            printf("unable to resolve\n");
            return false;
        }

        switch (host->h_addrtype)
        {
            case AF_INET:
            case AF_INET6:
                break;

            default:
                printf("resolved host type is not supported\n");
                return false;
        }

        for(char **addr = host->h_addr_list; *addr != 0; ++addr)
        {
            bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
            int addrlen;

            switch (host->h_addrtype)
            {
                case AF_INET:
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&server_address;
                    saddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
                    bcopy(*addr, &(saddr->sin_addr), host->h_length);
                    saddr->sin_port = htons(port_number);
                    addrlen = sizeof(*saddr);
                    break;
                }

                case AF_INET6:
                {
                    struct sockaddr_in6 *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&server_address;
                    saddr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
                    bcopy(*addr, &(saddr->sin6_addr), host->h_length);
                    saddr->sin6_port = htons(port_number);
                    addrlen = sizeof(*saddr);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (connect_to_addr((struct sockaddr*)&server_address, addrlen) != 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    return (local_socket != -1);
}
```

```
if (connect_to_host("device.local", 6666))
{
    // use local_socket as needed...
    close(local_socket);
}
```

Here is a `getaddrinfo()` example:

```
int connect_to_addr(const sockaddr *addr, int addrlen)
{
    local_socket = socket(addr->sa_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (local_socket == -1)
    {
        printf("unable to create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    unsigned short port;

    switch (addr->sa_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(saddr->sin6_addr), str, sizeof(str));
            port = ntohs(saddr->sin_port);
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *saddr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(saddr->sin6_addr), str, sizeof(str));
            port = ntohs(saddr->sin6_port);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("connecting to address: %s on port: %hu\n", str, port);

    if (connect(local_socket, addr, addrlen) != 0)
    {
        printf("unable to connect\n");

        close(local_socket);
        local_socket = -1;

        return 0;
    }

    printf("connected\n");
    return 1;
}
```

```
bool connect_to_host(const char* hostname, unsigned short port)
{
    local_socket = -1;

    printf("resolving %s:%hu\n", hostname, port);

    struct addrinfo hints;
    bzero((void *)&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    char service[6];
    bzero(service, sizeof(service));
    sprintf(service, "%hu", port_number);

    struct addrinfo *addrs = 0;
    if (getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &addrs) != 0)
    {
        printf("unable to resolve\n");
        return false;
    }

    for(struct addrinfo *addr = addrs; addr != 0; addr = addr->ai_next)
    {
        if (connect_to_addr((struct sockaddr*)(addr->ai_sockaddr), addr->ai_addrlen) != 0)
            break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);

    return (local_socket != -1);
}
```

```
if (connect_to_host("device.local", 6666))
{
    // use local_socket as needed...
    close(local_socket);
}
```

> How do I set up my TCP socket server to answer that address?

You simply `bind()` your listening socket to a specific IP address that is local to your server machine (use `getifaddrs()` or equivalent API to get a list of local IPs). Or use a wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY` for IPv4, `in6addr_any` for IPv6) to bind to all available local IPs.

DNS lookups on the client side will take care of resolving `device.local` to an IP address that routes to your server machine, and if your server socket is listening on that IP then it can `accept()` incoming connections.

Comment: I don't think so. "*Which format do I specify if I want my client to telnet to "hostname" instead of a numeric or hex address?*" - that is what I answered, how a client can resolve a hostname into an IP so it can then connect to that host. The fact that the hostname ends with `.local` is irrelevant, the DNS system handles that on the client's behalf. In this case, internally by `gethostbyname()` and `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: strictly speaking, it's the system resolver that decides whether to use DNS or /etc/hosts or mDNS (choosing the latter if the name matches the locally configured mDNS domain name, defaulted to `.local`).   In retrospect it's not 100% clear, but the OP appeared to be asking ("How do I set up my TCP socket server to answer that address?") how to use `inet_ntop()` to pick the address to `bind()` to, to which the answer is "don't - use `INADDR_ANY`"

Comment: This is useful!